# How can I specifiy the drive letter (windows) for the PROVIDER_URL of the JNDI InitialContext

Tags: java, windows, jms, jndi, initial-context

I am using the `com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory` file based JNDI context factory. It seems to take the drive of the where the java application is started in.

```
Hashtable properties = new Hashtable(2);
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"file:///tmp/jms/mycontext");
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
```

How can I specify the drive letter such as `d:/tmp/jms/mycontext` ? 
Using `file://d:/tmp/jms/mycontext` seems to still go to the c drive on my system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some troubleshooting and debugging myself I figured it out. Using an extra \ before the drive letter solves it

```
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"file://\\d:\\tmp\\mycontext");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

`"file:D:\\tmp\\jms\\mycontext"`

There are some examples in a tutorial at developerWorks that may be useful:
*[IBM WebSphere Developer Technical Journal: Running a standalone Java application on WebSphere MQ V6.0](http://bit.ly/c6jlIW)*

Comment: actually that does not work as file://d:/tmp/jms/mycontext or file:D:\\tmp\\jms\\mycontext still goes to the drive that is used to start java and if java is started from C: it looks for c:/tmp/jms/context

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  It works perfectly for me.  I'm using IBM's Java 6.0 implementation though.

Comment: You could be right it depends on the java implementation. Didn't work for me with java 5 and eclipse as my development environment

Answer (score 0):

`"file:///D:/temp"` worked for me